# What's the complete list of header,libraries and dlls to compile ,link and run PHP from source in windows?

Tags: php, windows-7, compilation

Any REAL geek can share this information right here?

Answer (score 2):

Please follow the Wiki below. If any of the steps fail, you can ask a specific question.

http://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild

Comment: "PHP officially supports building with Visual C++ 6.0 or with Visual C++ 9 (also known as Visual C++ 2008 just to be confusing)", so you have the compiler required in Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: I have the compiler and the VS 2008 ready,but can't open the .dsw project files shipped with PHP...

Comment: I believe the instructions there are for command-line building. You shouldn't have to open the project files.